# Есть много дивов, изначально показан толко первый, остальные скрыты, внутри каждого есть ссылка при нажатии на которую открывается следующий див

Tags: jquery

Есть 13 дивов, изначально показан толко первый, остальные скрыты, внутри каждого есть ссылка при нажатии на которую открывается следующий  див, а предыдущие скрываются, задала первому класс active, все дивы в контейнере. Что то уперлась, не знаю как дальше...

````
    e.preventDefault();
    var container = $('.container');
       for (var i = 0; i < 13; i ++) {
    container.find('div').eq(i).next().toggleClass('active');}
  });```
````

Comment: А как ссылка открывать следующий таргет или скриптом? Добавьте код этих блоков

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать в Vanilla JavaScript

```js
document.getElementById("link1").onclick = function() {
document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("div2").style.display = "block";
}
```

Мы регистрируем событие `onClick` на ссылку, и при его срабатывании скрываем первый div, и показываем 2 div

Осталось так сделать на всё divы, и всё

Answer (score 0):

При правильном подходе неважно, сколько элементов в контейнере. Нужно найти текущий div (родитель ссылки, на которую было нажатие) и следующий за ним. Соответственно, меняем видимость этих элементов:

```js
$('.container div').not(':first').hide();

$('.container div a').click(function(event) {
  let curDiv = $(event.target).parent();
  let nextDiv = curDiv.next();

  if (nextDiv.length) {
    $(nextDiv).show();
    $(curDiv).fadeOut();
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div><a href="#">Link 1</a></div>
  <div><a href="#">Link 2</a></div>
  <div><a href="#">Link 3</a></div>
  <div><a href="#">Link 4</a></div>
  <div><a href="#">Link 5</a></div>
  <div><a href="#">Link 6</a></div>
</div>
```

`fadeOut()` применил только для наглядности.